# why I get an exception "the file has been modified by..." when changing fields?

Tags: exception, form-library

I'm trying to change a field in the inner xlm of a document in a form library in Sharepoint 2013 but when I try to save the changes (second time, I click the Save button two times) I got an exception "the file has been modified by ...."

I put below my code that I use inside the itemupdated event receiver:

```
    public void SetValueToSPListItemXml(SPListItem item, string node, string value, SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                SPFile file = item.File;



                byte[] xmlFile = file.OpenBinary();
 XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmlFile))
                {
                   // MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(xmlFile);
                    xml.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                    xml.Load(ms);
                   // ms.Close();
                }


                bool itemFound = false;
                XmlNodeList nodes = xml.GetElementsByTagName("my:" + node);
                foreach (XmlNode nodex in nodes)
                {
                    nodex.InnerText = value;
                    itemFound = true;
                }

                //Get binary data for new XML
                byte[] xmlData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml.OuterXml);


                // only if we found the item we save it
                if (itemFound)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream myOutStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        xml.Save(myOutStream);
                        file.SaveBinary(myOutStream.ToArray());

                    }



                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                addLog(ex.Message.ToString() + " trying to change the " + node + " to:" + value, "", properties);

            }
            finally
            {
                 properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            }



        }
```

Comment: is there a event handler attached to library ?

Comment: I use this function inside the itemupdated event receiver, I have changed the synchronishm of the event receiver and it seems that works, I have to test it. what I have added is this line in elements.xml   <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint 2007 the after event was always asynchronous and fired on a separate thread as it allowed to perform some post processing work after the operation has been completed.

From a performance perspective this design is great as it avoids delaying operation while the post processing is done. But it limits the functionality that can be achieved in such an after event. E.g. as the after event fires asynchronously on a different thread it is not guaranteed that the code implemented in an after event has been completed when additional operations are performed later. As the processing of the after event also fires on a different thread it is also not possible to redirect to a different page from within the after event as neither the HttpContext object from the request initiating the original operation is available nor is it guaranteed that the after event is executed before the response of the original request has been sent back to the browser.

To overcome this limitation SharePoint 2010 has additional functionality to allow synchronous execution of after events. The default is still asynchronous but you can now configure your after event explicitly to execute synchronous.

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<Receivers ListTemplateId="850">
  <Receiver>       
    <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
  </Receiver>     
</Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Thanks nikhil, I have tested and it works although some times I got the error again (In addition sometimes I change the name of the file), there are other clues about this?